# How do I pass build or release attributes to an Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am building a data store which requires certain values from the pipeline.

Using the invoke azure function works if I hard code values, however, it does not work if I want build or release values on the fly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-function?view=azure-devops

My function requires a build number, however when I try adding the following to the query parameters it sends the words instead of the values:

```
BuildNumber=$($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)
```

or

```
BuildNumber=$env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
```

or
    BuildNumber=$(build.BUILDNUMBER)

YAML

```
variables:
  ApplicationCI: 'Test'

steps:
- task: AzureFunction@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function: https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/address'
  inputs:
    function: 'https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/Address'
    key: 'MyKey=='
    method: GET
    queryParameters: 'ApplicationCI=$(ApplicationCI)&BuildNumber=$(build.BUILDNUMBER)&ring=-1&BuildDefinitionName=$(build.DEFINITIONNAME)&BuildOwnerId=$(build.QUEUEDBY)&BuildStartTime=$(system.PIPELINESTARTTIME)&ChangeSet=$(build.SOURCEVERSION)&ReleaseDefinitionName=$(release.DEFINITIONNAME)&ReleaseStart=$(release.DEPLOYMENT_STARTTIME)&SourceLocation=$(build.SOURCEBRANCH)&StagingFolder=$(system.ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY)'
```

or

```
variables:
  ApplicationCI: 'Test'

steps:
- task: AzureFunction@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function: https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/address'
  inputs:
    function: 'https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/address'
    key: 'MyKey=='
    method: POST
    headers: |
     {
     "ApplicationCI":"$(ApplicationCI)", 
     "BuildNumber": "$(build.BUILDNUMBER)", 
     "ring": "-1", 
     "BuildDefinitionName": "$(build.DEFINITIONNAME)", 
     "BuildOwnerId": "$(build.QUEUEDBY)", 
     "BuildStartTime": "$(system.PIPELINESTARTTIME)", 
     "ChangeSet": "$(build.SOURCEVERSION)", 
     "ReleaseDefinitionName": "$(release.DEFINITIONNAME)", 
     "ReleaseStart": "$(release.DEPLOYMENT_STARTTIME)",
     "SourceLocation": "$(build.SOURCEBRANCH)",
     "StagingFolder": "$(system.ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY)"
     }
```

Does anyone have advice on how I can code the variable value for a build number into my invoke azure function call?

**UPDATES**
Changing to get gets me closer

https://site.azurewebsites.net/api/address?code=mykey==&ApplicationCI=Test 1&BuildNumber=20190508.4&ring=-1&BuildDefinitionName=MyApplication-AzureFunction&BuildOwnerId=$(build.QUEUEDBY)&BuildStartTime=$(system.PIPELINESTARTTIME)&ChangeSet=23624&ReleaseDefinitionName=MyApplication-AzureFunction&ReleaseStart=$(release.DEPLOYMENT_STARTTIME)&SourceLocation=$/test/Main&StagingFolder=$(system.ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY)

```
Apparently I only need values for these
$(build.QUEUEDBY)
$(system.PIPELINESTARTTIME)
$(release.DEPLOYMENT_STARTTIME)
$(system.ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY)

Thanks everyone for your help so far.
```

Comment: are you using azure function v1 or v2?

Comment: I only have 0.* (Preview) and 1.*. I am using 1.*

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure which version you are using but way to go would be to set build number in assembly and read it.

With .net core you can do `dotnet publish --version-suffix $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`  (If you don't use dotnet publish you can use azure pipeline set assembly information task to do the same) then in your code

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

PS. Haven't tested it but it should work

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over this. I am attempting to use the "Invoke Azure Function" task within Azure devOps. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-function?view=azure-devops 

I need to supply the values to either the headers for post or Query parameters for get. 

I have also tried $(build.BUILDNUMBER) which also does not work.

Comment: @john can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, please reread. Enter does not create a newline it submits the post. ;|

Comment: @john ca you please update your question with yaml you use?

Comment: Thanks, you got me where I needed to get.

Comment: @john glad to help :)